# How do you output a String based on Input with JOptionsPane

Tags: java, netbeans, joptionpane

I'm quite new to Java so this might be quite a surface-skimming question.

I'm making a login system and I want to make a message show up at 3 attempts prompting and then if you enter the correct input, it would output another new string.

Below is the code for the prompt so far. (I'm coding in NetBeans IDE)

P.S. This project is just for funzies so there is no risk for this outrageous behavior in a login system.

```
if(attempt == 3)
        {
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Give meh cupcakes", "Login Systems", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        }
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: "it would output another new string" what do you mean by this?

Comment: Unless you extend `JOptionPane`, you would have to call `showInputDialog` (or whatever dialog you choose) a second time to change the text.

Comment: You do it this way: `String stringInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Give meh cupcakes", "Login Systems", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE); System.out.println(stringInput);`

Comment: Output another string means that if you answer the question in the input dialog, then it would output another string or set a boolean to true.